# Warnings when passing arguments to a function

Tags: c, c-strings, string-literals, function-declaration

So I have a code that works how it has to work, but I am getting the "warning: passing argument 2 of 'outsideBettingHistory' from incompatible pointer type", why is that?
My project is huge so I will only rewrite parts that play the role in the warning, so you can paste it yourself and get the same errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct Bet {
    char* bets[3][2];
} Bet;

void outsideBettingHistory(int x, char betChosen[0][10], bool won, int result) {
    //You can ignore what is inside this function
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("bettingHistory.txt", "a");
    if(!f) {
        printf("\nThe bettingHistory.txt not found or unable to open");
        exit(0);
    }
    if(won) {
        fprintf(f, "%s %s", "Bet type: ", betChosen[0]);
        fprintf(f, ". Won %d credits\n", result);
    }
    if(!won) {
        fprintf(f, "%s %s", "Bet type: ", betChosen[0]);
        fprintf(f, ". Lost %d credits\n", result);
    }
    fclose(f);
}

int betColours(int balance, Bet* betTypes) {
      //A lot of stuff that have nothing to do with the warning

      int typeOfBet = 0; //This is the example of 3 variables that this function would give to the outsideBettingHistory(); function
      bool won = false;
      int resultAmount = 8;

      outsideBettingHistory(typeOfBet, betTypes->bets[0][typeOfBet], won, resultAmount);
      return balance;
}


int main() {
     int balance = 100;
     Bet betTypes = { .bets={{"Red", "Black"}, {"Even", "Odd"}, {"1 to 18", "19 to 36"}}};
     betColours(balance, &betTypes);
}
```

Also, for `void outsideBettingHistory(int x, char betChosen[0][10], bool won, int result)` I am getting "note: expected 'char (*)[10]' but argument is of type 'char *'" How do I get rid of these warnings?

Comment: Pass arguments with the types your function expects. Ask yourself: what does your funciton expect? What are you passing?

Comment: Is the error message not clear? The function is expecting a pointer to an array of 10 chars, but you're passing it a `char*`. You need to either pass a variable of the right type, or change the function to take a different type of parameter.

Comment: Norbertas,  Do you really want to use `betChosen[0]` twice in  `outsideBettingHistory()`?  It affects the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this call

```
outsideBettingHistory(typeOfBet, betTypes->bets[0][typeOfBet], won, resultAmount);
```

the second argument has the type `char *` because the data member bets is a two-dimensional array of pointers of the type `char *` and you selected the element of the array `bets[0][typeOfBet]` that is the same as `bets[0][0]` because `typeOfBet` was initialized by `0`. That is you passed to the function a pointer to the first character of the string literal `"Red"`.

But the second parameter of the function `outsideBettingHistory`

```
void outsideBettingHistory(int x, char betChosen[0][10], bool won, int result) {
```

has the type `char ( * )[10]`.

And the types are not compatible. So the compiler issues an error.

You should decide for yourself what you are trying to pass to the function and what the function shall do.

If it is supposed that the function `outsideBettingHistory` must deal with a string literal (an element of the two-dimensional array) then declare the function like

```
void outsideBettingHistory(int x, const char *betChosen, bool won, int result) {
```

Comment: So how do I change the 2nd argument the ```void outsideBettingHistory(int x, char betChosen[0][10], bool won, int result)``` function expects, so it still gets the string I passed to it, and I can use it for printing it into a .txt file? Sorry just pointers are my downside and I just don't know how to change that parameter so I still get the string and get rid of the warning

Comment: @Norbertas Change it to const char *betChosen. And do not use subscript operators within the function with thgis pointer unless you are going to access a character of the passed string literal

Comment: Thank you a lot!!